# Word for people or group(s) that will receive message

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a single word that means 'the people or group(s) that will receive the message'?

**Update:**

This will be used in my code. It will be part of the name of a class that will display who will receive the message that is being composed.

Comment: *recipients*....

Comment: Our Help Center says: [*But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site.* • **Naming, including naming programming variables/classes**](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 12):

A good one I thought of is *Recipients*. To me this word makes me think of someone who received an award. But it might fit my requirements.

Comment: I'm still open for other suggestions!

Comment: In information theory, it's the sender, recipient, channel and message.

Answer (score 8):

The broadest sense of **audience** covers this.

> *audience* n. ...
>
> 2. the persons reached by a book, radio or television broadcast, etc.; public.

[[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/audience)]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the noun 'addressees', which refers to the people to whom the message is addressed.

Comment: I like this. It meets the original criteria by implication, and doesn't sound forced.

Comment: an addresse might not be a recipient.

Answer (score 3):

The **addressee** would be the person to whom the message was addressed.  ie: the person or persons *intended* to receive it.

The **recipient** is the person who *actually did receive it.*

In an ideal world these two terms would refer to the same person, of course, but there are potential cases where they might not.  Up to the OP whether this distinction is important or not.

Answer (score 2):

How about: prospect, target or focus...
or more clinical: demographics, as the demographics of a marketing campaign, the (type of) people or culture you are trying to reach.
The problem with some of these terms is that they don't easily fit in conversations with those people on the receiving end.

Answer (score -1):

'recipiendary' is a people/thing about to receive something.

Comment: I can only find it as a rare word meaning a person about to *be* received (into society), akin to *debutante*, and apparently also used once in literature as a synonym for (or a mistake for) *receptacle*. This is not the word the OP is looking for.